# Select rows from table with jsonb column based on arbitrary jsonb filter expression

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

Test data

```
DROP TABLE t;
CREATE TABLE t(_id serial PRIMARY KEY, data jsonb);
INSERT INTO t(data) VALUES
   ('{"a":1,"b":2, "c":3}')
   , ('{"a":11,"b":12, "c":13}')
   , ('{"a":21,"b":22, "c":23}')
```

Problem statement: I want to receive an arbitrary JSONB parameter which acts as a filter on column `t.data`, such as

```
{ "b":{ "from":0, "to":20 }, "c":13 }
```

and use this to select matching rows from my test table `t`.
In this example, I want rows where `b` is between 0 and 20 and `c` = 13.
No error is required if the filter specifies a "column" (or "tag") which does not exist in `t.data` - it just fails to find a match.

I've used numeric values for simplicity but would like an approach which generalises to `text` as well.

What I have tried so far. I looked at the containment approach, which works for equality conditions, but am stumped on a generic way of handling range conditions:

```
select * from t
where t.data@> '{"c":13}'::jsonb;
```

Background: This problem arose when building a generic table-preview page on a website (for Admin users).
The page displays a filter based on various columns in whichever table is selected for preview.
The filter is then passed to a function in Postgres DB which applies this dynamic filter condition to the table.
It returns a jsonb array of the rows matching the filter specified by the user.
This jsonb array is then used to populate the Preview resultset.
The columns which make up the filter may change.

My Postgres version is 9.6 - thanks.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-json.html

Comment: I could use containment operator for equality conditions, but not sure about range conditions (eg where I want "b" to be between 0 and 20).

Comment: There is no generic (or built-in) way to do that. You will need to write your own JSON parser, analyze the query parameter and build the appropriate condition for the stored JSON. You might want to look into GraphQL which provides a parser infrastructure for  that.

Answer (score 1):

if you  want to parse `{ "b":{ "from":0, "to":20 }, "c":13 }` you need a parser. It is out of scope of json functions, but you can write "generic" query using `AND` and `OR` to filter by such json, eg:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jAPBQggG3p7CxqbKLMbPKw/0

```
with filt(f) as (values('{ "b":{ "from":0, "to":20 }, "c":13 }'::json))
select * 
from t
join filt on 
 (f->'b'->>'from')::int < (data->>'b')::int 
 and 
 (f->'b'->>'to')::int > (data->>'b')::int 
 and
 (data->>'c')::int = (f->>'c')::int
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments/suggestions.
I will definitely look at GraphQL when I have more time - I'm working under a tight deadline at the moment.
It seems the consensus is that a fully generic solution is not achievable without a parser.
However, I got a workable first draft - it's far from ideal but we can work with it. Any comments/improvements are welcome ...

Test data (expanded to include dates & text fields)

```
DROP TABLE t;
CREATE TABLE t(_id serial PRIMARY KEY, data jsonb);
INSERT INTO t(data) VALUES
   ('{"a":1,"b":2, "c":3, "d":"2018-03-10", "e":"2018-03-10", "f":"Blah blah" }')
   , ('{"a":11,"b":12, "c":13, "d":"2018-03-14", "e":"2018-03-14", "f":"Howzat!"}')
   , ('{"a":21,"b":22, "c":23, "d":"2018-03-14", "e":"2018-03-14", "f":"Blah blah"}')
```

First draft of code to apply a jsonb filter dynamically, but with restrictions on what syntax is supported.
Also, it just fails silently if the syntax supplied does not match what it expects.
Timestamp handling a bit kludgey, too.

```
-- Handle timestamp & text types as well as int
-- See is_timestamp(text) function at bottom

with cte as (
    select t.data, f.filt, fk.key
    from t
    , ( values ('{ "a":11, "b":{ "from":0, "to":20 }, "c":13, "d":"2018-03-14", "e":{ "from":"2018-03-11", "to": "2018-03-14" }, "f":"Howzat!" }'::jsonb ) ) as f(filt) -- equiv to cross join
    , lateral (select * from jsonb_each(f.filt)) as fk
)
select data, filt       --, key, jsonb_typeof(filt->key), jsonb_typeof(filt->key->'from'), is_timestamp((filt->key)::text), is_timestamp((filt->key->'from')::text) 
from cte
where 
    case when (filt->key->>'from') is null then 
        case jsonb_typeof(filt->key) 
            when 'number' then (data->>key)::numeric = (filt->>key)::numeric
            when 'string' then 
                case is_timestamp( (filt->key)::text )
                    when true then (data->>key)::timestamp = (filt->>key)::timestamp
                    else (data->>key)::text = (filt->>key)::text
                end
            when 'boolean' then (data->>key)::boolean = (filt->>key)::boolean
            else false
        end
    else 
        case jsonb_typeof(filt->key->'from') 
            when 'number' then (data->>key)::numeric between (filt->key->>'from')::numeric and (filt->key->>'to')::numeric
            when 'string' then 
                case is_timestamp( (filt->key->'from')::text )
                    when true then (data->>key)::timestamp between (filt->key->>'from')::timestamp and (filt->key->>'to')::timestamp
                    else (data->>key)::text between (filt->key->>'from')::text and (filt->key->>'to')::text
                end
            when 'boolean' then false
            else false
        end
    end
group by data, filt
having count(*) = ( select count(distinct key) from cte ) -- must match on all filter elements
;

create or replace function is_timestamp(s text) returns boolean as $$
begin
  perform s::timestamp;
  return true;
exception when others then
  return false;
end;
$$ strict language plpgsql immutable;
```